# How to set the correct indentation of indentation guides?

Tags: monaco-editor

Enabling indentation guides in Monaco is done by setting `renderIndentGuides` to true in `Monaco.IEditorOptions`. However this results in indentation guides that are not properly indented:

[image]

Language in the editor is set to "javascript" and tabstops are disabled (thus using the the default of 4 spaces for one indentation step). Which setting must be changed to make the indentation guides follow the set indentation width in the editor?

Comment: Strange. For me that works fine, and I don't use `renderIndentGuides`.

Comment: And sometimes it **does** work correctly. That's the most confusing thing. And then suddenly it starts acting strangely. Maybe a hidden bug with a not initialized variable inside Monaco? I triple checked my code to see if I do something wrong, but couldn't find any indication for doing so.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot confirm that this solves the issue since I'm not able to fully reproduce it, but for those who land here looking for an advanced indentation configuration, here is my example configuration for XML language, containing multiple options you can play around with in [Monaco editor playground](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html). (just copy, paste, run):

```js
monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById('container'), {
    value: "<group>\n<content>\n<value text=\"Press Ctrl + Shift + F\">\</value>\n</content>\n</group>",
    language: "xml",
    tabSize: 2,
    autoIndent: "full",
    detectIndentation: true,
    formatOnType: true,
    formatOnPaste: true,
});

monaco.languages.setLanguageConfiguration("xml", {
    "indentationRules": {
        "increaseIndentPattern": new RegExp("<(?!\\?|[^>]*\\/>)([-_.A-Za-z0-9]+)(?=\\s|>)\\b[^>]*>(?!.*<\\/\\1>)|<!--(?!.*-->)|\\{[^}\"']*$"),
        "decreaseIndentPattern": new RegExp("^\\s*(<\\/(?!html)[-_.A-Za-z0-9]+\\b[^>]*>|-->|})"),
    },
});

monaco.editor.addKeybindingRules([
    {
        // Reindent lines with Ctrl + Shift + F
        keybinding: monaco.KeyMod.CtrlCmd | monaco.KeyMod.Shift | monaco.KeyCode.KeyF,
        command: "editor.action.reindentlines",
    },
]);
```

`indentationRules` are borrowed from [vscode HTML extension configuration](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/main/extensions/html/language-configuration.json) and simplified. More information about it [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/language-configuration-guide#indentation-rules).